# calcular uma função probabilidade em R

Tags: r

Boa tarde.

É a minha primeira intervenção no stack, sou iniciante no `R`, e as minhas dúvidas são bastantes básicas.

Preciso gerar uma amostra de 1000 observações de uma função de distribuição de `W`.
`W` é uma variável aleatória discreta, que assume os valores de `1` a `6`, representada pelos lados de um dado, dado este que está viciado e cuja função probabilidade é `p1=0.25`, `p2=0.16`, `p3=0.18`, `p4=0.17`, `p5=0.14`, `p6=0.10`.

Como posso escrever essa função em R?

Obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma de você resolver esse problema é utilizando a função de distribuição acumulada inversa dessa variável.

Você sabe as probabilidades da variável `X` assumir cada um dos possíveis valores (de `1` a `6`), então é possível construir a função de distribuição acumulada (`F(x) = P(X <= x)`):

`F(x)` =

- 0,25 se X <= 1;
- 0,41 se X <= 2;
- 0,59 se X <= 3;
- 0,76 se X <= 4;
- 0,90 se X <= 5;
- 1,00 se X <= 6

Então, utilizando o conceito de função inversa `F(x)^(-1)`, gere uma probabilidade e tenha o valor da variável.

`F(x)^(-1)`:

- 1 se 0 < p < 0,25;
- 2 se 0,25 < p < 0,41;
- 3 se 0,41 < p < 0,59;
- 4 se 0,59 < p < 0,76;
- 5 se 0,76 < p < 0,90;
- 6 se 0,90 < p < 1,00

No `R` você gera "uma probabilidade" com a função `runif()`. Sendo assim, segue código que gera valores dessa sua variável aleatória:

```
gerar.VA <- function(n = 1){
  #P(X=1) = 0,25; P(X=2) = 0,16; P(X=3) = 0,18 ;P(X=4) = 0,17; P(X=5) = 0,14; P(X=6) = 0,10
  resultado <- NULL
  aux <- runif(n)
  for(i in 1:n){
    if(aux[i] < 0.25){
      resultado[i] <- 1
    } else{
      if(aux[i] < 0.25 + 0.16){
        resultado[i] <- 2
      } else{
        if(aux[i] < 0.25 + 0.16 + 0.18){
          resultado[i] <- 3
        } else{
          if(aux[i] < 0.25 + 0.16 + 0.18 + 0.17){
            resultado[i] <- 4
          } else{
            if(aux[i] < 0.25 + 0.16 + 0.18 + 0.17 + 0.14){
              resultado[i] <- 5
            } else{
              resultado[i] <- 6
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return(resultado)
}
gerar.VA(n = 1000)
```

Answer (score 4):

Para amostrar de uma variável discreta que toma um número finito de valores, pode-se usar a função base `sample`.
Antes de correr a função `sample` ou outra função que gere números pseudo-aleatórios, é sempre melhor chamar `set.seed`.

```
set.seed(7228)

W <- 1:6
p <- c(0.25, 0.16, 0.18, 0.17, 0.14, 0.10)
w <- sample(W, 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = p)

head(w, n = 20)
#[1] 4 4 1 3 6 3 5 4 1 1 2 4 4 4 4 2 6 6 5 6
```

Ver se as proporções do resultado são semelhantes às probabilidades dadas.

```
tw <- table(w)
print(tw/sum(tw), digits = 2)
#w
#   1    2    3    4    5    6 
#0.23 0.16 0.16 0.19 0.14 0.12
```

Não parecem ser muito diferentes. Se for preciso, sempre se pode correr um teste de Kolmogorov-Smirnov, uma vez que tanto `p` como as proporções da amostra vêm de uma distribuição contínua.

```
ks.test(p, tw/sum(tw))
```

Com um `p-value = 0.8928` concui-se que sim, que as distribuições não são significativamente diferentes.